# How can I use windows defender? And should I?

Tags: windows, windows-defender

I've heard that windows defender is pretty good but microsoft is forced to turn it off.

I just uninstalled avira. However, I still cannot turn on windows defender

If I open windows defender I simply got a message that it's turned off with no option to turn it back on at all

[image]

I go to services and try to run the service my self. I got 577 error

http://www.besttechtips.org/how-to-fix-windows-defender-error-577-in-windows-10/

I have no idea what to do. Will try some of the advice there.

Comment: We need more information.  What version of Windows?  Windows Defender in Windows 7 is an entirely different thing then Windows Defender on Windows 10.  You should just be able to launch Windows Defender (its installed on either Windows 7 or Windows 10 unless you specifically removed it) and enable it.

Comment: See if Avira's manual uninstall procedure helps. http://www.avira.com/en/support-for-home-knowledgebase-detail/kbid/902

Comment: How exactly I should enable it?

Comment: Cleanly uninstalling 3rd party AV should be enough. Defender will turn on automatically in the next restart.

Comment: It doesn't. And that's why I make this question. If it were that easy I wouldn't have asked.

Comment: In Windows Services check to be sure "Windows Defender" service is set to "Automatic" and is started, if not set to automatic and start the service.

Comment: You mean you tried the avira's uninstaller in the link I posted and still doesn't work?

Answer (score 0):

First, make sure Avira is completely uninstalled. In this case, you'll need to follow their [manual uninstallation procedure](https://www.avira.com/en/support-for-home-knowledgebase-detail/kbid/902). While booted into safe mode, delete all Avira directories under the `Program Files`, `Program Files (x86)`, and `ProgramData` folders, which you can find in the root of your OS drive. You can then run their registry cleaning tool to remove all traces of Avira.

If that doesn't help, try [running the System File Checker](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/929833) by typing `sfc /scannow` into an elevated command prompt.

You could also restart the Security Center service (with `services.msc`).

Source and further reading: [this Microsoft wiki article](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/protect/wiki/protect_defender-protect_start/problems-starting-windows-defender-in-windows/808253bb-db89-4db9-a4e5-1c91a86489e9).